# How do I use a JavaScript variable to refer to more than 2 values in different conditions?

Tags: javascript

hey am trying to write a JavaScript simple game program, my program has two players 1 and 2, i want to write a statement trying to say that "if it is turn for player , add a hidden class to a certain element, and execute some conditions. and if it is player 2 turn, do the same". Yes i know one way of doing it but it is quite long and i wanna try it this way but am getting an error, what can i do. Below is part of my code.

```js
"using strict";

const PLAYER_1_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".player-1");
const PLAYER_2_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".player-2");
const TOTAL_1_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".total-1");
const TOTAL_2_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".total-2");
const BTN_TRY_LUCK = document.querySelector(".top");
const BTN_RESET_LUCK = document.querySelector(".bottom");
const CURRENT_1_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".borders-1");
const CURRENT_2_ELEMENT = document.querySelector(".borders-2");
const IMAGES_1 = document.querySelector(".images-1");
const IMAGES_2 = document.querySelector(".images-2")


let player = [1,2];

//statement giving me errors
IMAGES_${player[1]}.classList.add("hidden");

//below are the conditions i want it to execute

if(IMAGES_${player[1]}.classList.contains(".active")) {
    //...................
    //..................
}
```

Comment: `IMAGES_${player[1]}` <-- This is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: You can do that statically.  Just doing `IMAGES_2` instead of `IMAGES_${player[1]}` will work.

Comment: There is no statement in js like `"using strict"`. Use `"use strict"`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, let me try it out

Comment: Answered in ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this `IMAGES_${player[1]}` - it seems like you're trying to use a template string to reference a variable.

The code you have is invalid syntax to begin with as template strings need to be wrapped in backticks `` ` ``

This can be done, but you need to first reference the ***parent*** variable and then get the value by passing the variable name as the index. For example:

```
window[`IMAGES_${player[1]}`]
```

This would work assuming these variables are declared at the root and not within a separate scope.

To ensure you're calling the right variables regardless of scope, you could store them all in an object like so:

```js
"use strict";

const data = {
    PLAYER_1_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".player-1"),
    PLAYER_2_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".player-2"),
    TOTAL_1_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".total-1"),
    TOTAL_2_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".total-2"),
    BTN_TRY_LUCK : document.querySelector(".top"),
    BTN_RESET_LUCK : document.querySelector(".bottom"),
    CURRENT_1_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".borders-1"),
    CURRENT_2_ELEMENT : document.querySelector(".borders-2"),
    IMAGES_1 : document.querySelector(".images-1"),
    IMAGES_2 : document.querySelector(".images-2")
}


let player = [1,2];

//statement giving me errors
data[`IMAGES_${player[1]}`].classList.add("hidden");

//below are the conditions i want it to execute

if(data[`IMAGES_${player[1]}`].classList.contains(".active")) {
    //...................
    //..................
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `player[1]` is actually referencing player number 2 (due to 0 indexed arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating variables with calculated names and then referencing them, it is easier in JavaScript to generate an object containing arrays. This object (here: `elems`) can have local scope and does not have to be globally visible.

```js
const elems={};
"player,total,borders,images".split(",").forEach(el=>elems[el]=document.querySelectorAll(`[class^=${el}-]`));

// Now you can reference the player-related elements
// by doing:

// elems["borders"][0] ... // or
// elems.borders[0] ... // player 1

// elems["borders"][1] ... // or
elems.borders[1].classList.add("active") // player 2
```

```css
.active {color:red}
```

```html
<h2>Players 1 and 2</h2>
<div class="borders-1">player 1 borders element</div>
<div class="borders-2">player 2 borders element</div>
```

In the extremely shortened snippet above the object `elems` contains *collections* of DOM elements and not actual *arrays*. These collections contain player1 and player2 elements in the order they appear on the page. Elements within collections can be addressed by their index. Collections also have a `.forEach()` method but you will not have access to the customary array methods like `.map()` or `.reduce()`.

If you want to have *actual* arrays, simply create them by doing

```
arr=[...collection]
```

Comment: Hey i tried doing it in that way, i didnt get any errors but when i tried out printing some value on the console like;                    
 console.log(DATA[`TOTAL${player}_ELEMENT`].textContent)